# launch/cancel activity immediatly when conditions are met in a service

Tags: java, android, security, service

So I'm building an application locker for android.Ive written a service for my locker activity to launch as soon as a particular activity is detected on top on the android application stack.The list of applications to be locked are stored in a table in a database.For the most part my service works fine.But I'm facing some issues which i do not know how to overcome. Any help is greatfully accepted

I want to resolve the following issues.

1) When i press the back button i want my locker activity and The app which was being to locked to stop executing. In my case,the lockeractivity keeps on launching again and again when i press the back button.

2) When a particular app which need to be be locked launches, the app is shown on the screen for a 1 second or 2 before my locker activity gets called.i want my locker activity to be invoked directly.

3) And some times my locker activity is called again once a user has already verified himself which is do not want. (i think this is cause of the timing of the service to check the foreground activity)

My Service

```
public class LockerService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
String LockedApps[];
String allowedapp = null;
DataBaseHandler handler;

private final static Handler servicehandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new DataBaseHandler(this);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private Runnable checkforeground = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // / Any thing you want to do put the code here like web service
        // procees it will run in ever 1 second
        handler.open();
        LockedApps = handler.getPackages();
        handler.close();

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am
                .getRunningAppProcesses();
        String foregroundapp = runningAppProcessInfo.get(0).processName
                .toString();
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(LockerService.this);
        allowedapp = sp.getString("allowedapp", "anon");

        if ((Arrays.asList(LockedApps).contains(foregroundapp))
                && (allowedapp.equals(foregroundapp))) {
            // do nothing
        } else if (Arrays.asList(LockedApps).contains(foregroundapp)) {
            // show your activity here on top of
            // PACKAGE_NAME.ACTIVITY_NAME
            Intent lockIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Locker.class);
            lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            getBaseContext().startActivity(lockIntent);
        }
        servicehandler.postDelayed(this, 1500); // 1.5 seconds
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    servicehandler.removeCallbacks(checkforeground);
    servicehandler.postDelayed(checkforeground, 1500);// 1.5 second
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Override onBackPressed() method in locker activity and fire a intent to the home launcher. that is nothing but it will takes you to the home screen.